# Copying sectors?

Tags: linux

Is there a script i can use to copy some particular sectors of my Harddisk?

I actually have two partitions say A and B, on my Harddisk. Both are of same sizes. What i want is to run a program which starts copying data from the starting sector of A to the starting sector of B until the end sector of A is copied to the end sector of B.

Looking for possible solutions...

Thanks a lot

Comment: This probably belongs on SuperUser.com, not StackOverflow.

Comment: I need to program this behavior so that makes it belong to stackoverflow, i guess. :)

Comment: You might look into the `dd` command then, if this is a linux/unix system: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix) - note the example on that page specifically of using it to duplicate one partition onto another.

Comment: Yeah Dav. It's Linux. I have used dd for copying partitions but can I use it for copying sectors by specifying that start and end sectors?

Comment: You can use the `skip`/`seek` and the `count` options to specify positioning and size of the segment(s) to copy within the specified partition; so if you know the sector size you can compute the proper offset+size and pass those to `dd`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dav. I will look into it. But what if I need to copy sectors from within an unallocated region of Harddisk to some other unallocated region. Any idea?

Comment: I think what you need is a command, not a whole program.  Of course, you can include the command into a program, but `dd` should be all you need.  Take a look at janneb's answer.  It shows the proper syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about using `dd`? Following copies 1024 blocks (of 512 bytes size, which is usually a sector size) with 4096 block offset from sda to sdb partition:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1 bs=512 count=1024 skip=4096
```

PS. I also suppose it should be SuperUser or rather ServerFault question.

Comment: Thats very close but I don't have partition information. It's something like some data is hidden in unallocated region of Harddisk and I want to copy some sectors from that unallocated region to some other place in the same unallocated region. Which to me is only possible if i copy by specifying sectors. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: A disk is also a block device, so you may use it as an argument for `if=` and `of=` as well, e.g. `if=/dev/sda of=/tmp/any_file`

Comment: If you operate on the disk itself (eg `/dev/sda`), and use `bs=512`, then the `count` and `skip` will be effectively addressed as LBAs.

Comment: You can use `sudo fdisk -l` to see partition information.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to access the hard drive directly, not via partitions, then, well, just do that. Something like

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1024 skip=XX seek=YY
```

should copy 1024 sectors starting at sector XX to sectors YY->YY+1024. Of course, if the sector ranges overlap, results are probably not going to be pretty.

(Personally, I wouldn't attempt this without first taking a backup of the disk, but YMMV)

Comment: (your mileage may vary)

Comment: I totally agree with using dd to copy the entire partition before trying to pluck out pieces of it.  Also, the OP talks about sectors, but I suspect the whole issue is about files, which means more work to figure out the layout of how a particular file is stored on disk.  So yes, indeed, your mileage may vary as Ben said.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if what you are looking for is a partion copier.
If that is what you mean try clonezilla.
(it will show you what exact statement it uses so can be used to find out how to do that in a script afterwards)

Comment: Nah. I actually need to copy some particular sectors. That "Partition" was just an example. I need something that copies specified sectors.

Comment: janneb posted a good answer that shows how to seek to specific sectors by number.  So if you know that information you're set.  If all you know is a filename it can be done but is beyond the scope of this question.  Hennie is right about focusing on partitions first.  I use `dd` for that but others use CloneZilla as Hennie suggests.